# Ler múltiplos números na mesma linha com raw_input

Tags: python

Preciso escrever um programa que leia valores e posteriormente os use para calcular áreas de diferentes figuras geométricas. Meu problema é: como entrar com os dados na mesma linha? 
Exemplo:
3.0
4.0
2.0
 seguido do cálculo na proxima linha

Como escrever o código para que o Python leia na mesma linha? É mesmo com o raw_input?

Como estou fazendo:

```
a = float(raw_input())
b = float(raw_input())
c = float(raw_input()) 
triangulo = (a * c) / 2
print "TRIANGULO:", ("%.3f" % triangulo)
circulo = (3.14159 * c**2 )
print "CIRCULO:", ("%.3f" % circulo)
trapezio = ((a + b) * c) / 2
print "TRAPEZIO:", ("%.3f" % trapezio)
quadrado = b * b
print "QUADRADO:", ("%.3f" % quadrado)
retangulo = a * b
print "RETANGULO:", ("%.3f" % retangulo)
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291475/como-atribuir-3-valores-para-3-vari%c3%a1veis-em-apenas-uma-linha-de-entrada-em-pytho?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o `raw_input()` (no Python 2) ou o `input()` (no Python 3) e separar os dados através do `split`. Ou seja, ficaria assim:

```
entrada = raw_input("Digite três números") # lendo os números
# quebrando a entrada em tokens separados por espaço (poderia ser outro separador)
numerosComoString = entrada.split(" ")
# criando uma nova lista com a conversão para float de cada número
numeros = [float(numero) for numero in numerosComoString] 

# atribuindo cada posição da lista a uma variável
a, b, c = numeros
triangulo = (a * c) / 2
print "TRIANGULO:", ("%.3f" % triangulo)
circulo = (3.14159 * c**2 )
print "CIRCULO:", ("%.3f" % circulo)
trapezio = ((a + b) * c) / 2
print "TRAPEZIO:", ("%.3f" % trapezio)
quadrado = b * b
print "QUADRADO:", ("%.3f" % quadrado)
retangulo = a * b

print "RETANGULO:", ("%.3f" % retangulo)
```

Em Python 3, basta substituir `raw_input` por `input`.

Note que não está sendo feito nenhum tratamento de erros para entradas mal formatadas. Num código para uso real, isso seria essencial.

Comment: Basicamente, os valores de entrada a, b e c devem estar na mesma linhda.

Comment: Você quer dizer que uma linha de entrada contém 3 números separados por espaço?

Comment: Sim, quero dizer que é assim que deve ser, pelo menos de acordo com a Questão que devo resolver no The Huxley (imagino que conheça essa plataforma de interação entre alunos e professores).

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja como está agora. Tenha certeza de ter entendido cada linha pois essas coisas são fundamentais para seus próximos exercícios.

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso antes de você comentar e ele acusou erro de sintaxe na segunda linha, e vi que além do input eu tinha mudado "entrada" para "valores" na primeira linha, sem alterar a segunda. Tudo corrigido e funcionando. Muito obrigado Plabo! Tenha um bom dia.

Comment: Por nada. Não se esqueça de votar e marcar a resposta como aceita caso tenha te ajudado. Bons estudos!

Comment: Está feito. Obrigado.

Comment: Estou começando a estudar Python e sua reposta foi muito útil. Grato!

Comment: Muito útil, estava procurando como faz isso, python é lindo!!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código...

```
x = list(map(float, input('Digite os valores "A", "B" e "C": ').split()))

triangulo = ((x[0] * x[2]) / 2)
print("TRIANGULO:", "%.3f" % triangulo)
circulo = (3.14159 * x[2]**2)
print("CIRCULO:", "%.3f" % circulo)
trapezio = ((x[0] + x[1]) * x[2]) / 2
print("TRAPEZIO:", "%.3f" % trapezio)
quadrado = x[1] * x[1]
print("QUADRADO:", "%.3f" % quadrado)
retangulo = x[0] * x[1]
print("RETANGULO:", "%.3f" % retangulo)
```

**Como executar o algoritmo?**

Quando você executa este código você recebe a seguinte mensagem `Digite os valores "A", "B" e "C":`. Neste momento você deve digitar todos os `três` valores, na `mesma` linha, `separados` por um só espaço e, em seguida, pressionar `Enter`.

A partir deste momento, os valores digitados serão `capturados`, convertidos em `float` e adicionados à lista `x`.

A partir de então, os valores da lista serão recuperados através de seus índices, para em seguida, realizar os cálculos.