# Lista em Python

Tags: python

Como faço para receber 10 números inteiros e recebe-los separados por espaços numa mesma linha em lista e imprimi-los em ordem inversa.

Eu lembro que era algo assim:

```
variavelA, variavelB = input().split(' ')
```

Comment: Você não precisa atribuir em duas variáveis; como você mesmo colocou no título, utilize uma lista. O retorno de `split` será uma lista, atribuindo ela a uma variável apenas você poderá utilizar o `sorted` ou `sort` para classificá-la da maneira que desejar. Lembre-se que `input` sempre retorna uma *string*, então sua lista será de *strings*, não de números. faça a conversão antes de ordenar. Quer tentar?

Comment: Como faz isso usando a lista no Python?

Comment: [Ler múltiplos números na mesma linha com raw_input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115349/5878) | [Invertendo sequência (PYTHON 3)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192304/5878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo da premissa que o usuario vai digitar os numeros separados por espaços, isto é, já que tem que ser na mesma linha, não da para checar a cada digitacao (daria para fazer a checagem após a digitacao), mas, abstraindo essa checagem vc poderia fazer tudo uma única linha de comando:

```
print(' '.join((input('entre com os numros: ').split(' '))[::-1]))
```

Se o usuário entrar com `10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100`, vc teria a saida:

```
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

**Explicando separadamente:**
Explicando cada parte do comando partindo do centro para as extremidades.

`input('entre com os numros: ')`:
 
Recebe a digitação do usuário em um objeto na memoria, do tipo string;

`.split(' ')`:
Cria uma lista a partir da string digitada, onde cada elemento é a substring imediatamente anterior ao espaço.

`[::-1])`
Faz um slice, invertendo a lista.

`' '.join()`
Converte a lista para uma string de volta.

`print()`
Apresenta o resultado

**Implementando separadamente:**
Os mesmos comandos executados na linha única a cima, agora implementados separadamente:

```
# Inputando os números
numbers = input('entre com os numeros: ')

# Convertendo para uma lista:
lst_numbers = numbers.split(' ')

# Invertendo a lista
lst_inverted = lst_numbers[::-1] 

# Convertendo a lista invertida para uma string
str_inverted = ' '.join(lst_inverted)

# Apresentando o resultado
print(str_inverted)
```

Saída:

```
'100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10'
```

Comment: **lst_numbers = `.split(' ')** está com erro de identação.

Comment: @AlexFeliciano Na verdade não era na identação, eu copiei da parte de cima e acabei esquecendo de colocar a string original `numbers`, editei e corrigi, veja se funfa agora.

Comment: No seu código, por que o resultado não fica assim `['100', '90', '80', '70', '60', '50', '40', '30', '20', '10']` como uma lista, e ao invés disso fica `100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10`

Comment: Assim, como? Não Entendi.

Comment: No run.codes ele dá como incorreto pois ele quer os resultados dentro de uma lista desse modo `['100', '90', '80', '70', '60', '50', '40', '30', '20', '10']`

Comment: Vc esta apresentando a `str_inverted`, ou seja, a string invertida, para apresentar a lista invertida vc deve fazer: `print(lst_inverted)`, ou seja poderia suprimir os 2 ultimos comandos

Comment: Deu certo obrigado, é que eu esqueci que era pra imprimir inversamente

Answer (score 1):

Com a seguinte entrada: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`

A seguinte saída é obtida:

```
0
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Com o seguinte código:

```
[print(x) for x in input().split()[::-1]]
```

E uma lista inversa `['0', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']` com `input().split()[::-1]`

Comment: Como ficaria esse código sem usar o **FOR**?